# jenkins build on same node forcing entire tree to build on same node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Due to our insane abuse of git, part of the build/test sequence is jenkins checking out our multiple repositories, I then kick off debug and release build/test sequences. This also happens for multiple sets of git tags (ie release10, release11 ... concurrent development). The point is that once a server checks out a particular release for a particular type of build, that build/test sequence needs to stay on that server. The job sequence looks like this:

job A: kick off build/test of release X which triggers job B and job C which can happen in parallel on same or different servers

job B: git update/checkout release X debug build/test this then triggers job D which must be done on same node

job C: git update/checkout release X release build/test this then triggers job E which must be done on same node

job D: build/test continuing on same node

job E: build/test ....

so the tree looks like this:

```
                             A
                           /   \
                          B     C
                          |     |
                          D     E
                         ......
```

Jobs B and C have the "build on same node" which states that triggered builds need to happen on the same node as the current build.

Unfortunately what is also happening is that jobs B and C are being forced to run on the same node that job A ran on. This is not the behavior I want. Does the "build on same node" force the entire build tree to a particular node, which is not what the help says. Or is this a bug or ...

Comment: Where exactly did you set "Build on same node"? My understanding is that you need to set it in the build step of B when triggering D.

Comment: yes, i set the "build on same node" in the trigger for job D in job B, also in the trigger for job E on job C, but this appears to force jobs B & C to run on the same node as A which is not what i want.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Jenkins... looking forward to an answer.